# PUT ERROR 404 (Not Found) in playframework with restangular

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, scala, playframework, restangular

I have a list of customers diplayed in a table, and I'm using the same modal for add and update a customer so I do a test on the id to distinct if the click on the button  "add" is for adding or updating :

```
$scope.saveCustomer = function(customer){

    if ($scope.customer.uid){
        $scope.customer = customer;
        $scope.customer.contacts = customer.contacts;
        $scope.customer.put();
}
else{
        Restangular.all("customer").post(customer).then(function() {
        $scope.customerList.push(customer);
        console.log("success");
    },function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}
};
```

the add is working well but for the put I get this error :

[image]

UPDATE:

I should mention that I have a list contact in the customer object, so when I update my customer I update also some fields of Contact, and I'm using mongodb and I tested the put method on postman and it's working well

Comment: Looks as though the endpoint doesn't exist. How are your endpoints being generated?

Comment: I tested the url in the navigator and it shows all the data in Customer table so the url exists

Comment: the `GET` endpoint exists, but that doesn't mean any other verbs exist. Each one of the endpoints needs to be [supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)

Comment: Could you show the content of routes configuration file?

Comment: yes of course : http://pastebin.com/19JryXWp and please check the update

Answer (score 0):

According to your routes configuration you don't have route defined for method PUT to /customer location.

In your conf/routes try to add:

```
PUT     /customer                 controllers.CustomerController.__method_to_process_put__
```

Comment: I don't know what is the problem, I tested the method with postman and it's working well.